# How to Create Voronoi Texture with Vector Colors and Distance-Based Distortion in Blender

Tags: texturing, materials, mathematics, vector

I'm want to create a Voronoi Texture including colours for the vectors. In this context, the black dots you'd normally see on the Voronoi Texture are the origins of the coordinate systems, and also I'd like to ensure that the coordinates stretch and warp according to the distance to the edges.

I've successfully generated a Voronoi Texture (but only in black and white). For a more in-depth explanation of the entire node setup, you can refer to "Dr. Blender's" YouTube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N_A92pXHNtk&list=WL&index=1

My goal is to blend Input1 and Input2 similarly to how Value1 and Value2 are mixed. Ultimately, when I plug the resulting vector into a length node, I want it to produce the same results (the Length node is just for demonstration purposes). I've attempted to achieve this using a Vector Math node with the "Minimum" operation, but that hasn't given me the desired outcome.

[image: supposedResult] [image: currentOutcome]

I'm now open to any suggestions or ideas on how to achieve this.

You can access the .blend file on OneDrive: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AoOHD-HUvUa1hK5UG3saPIet1e5Mrg?e=tAaeVr

Thank you in advance for any help or insights. In case of any questions, please feel free to ask.

Best Regards,
Hagen

Answer (score 1):

The *Minimum* operation of a *Vector Math* node performs component wise, using this will produce very short vectors with mingled coordinates. You need to compare the lengths of the vectors.

First create a new *Node Group* like this and call it `Shorter Vector`. This node group will return the vector with lesser length:

[image]

Now use that new node group and edit *NodeGroup.012* to look like this (and change the type of `tmp_viewer` to *Vector*). As one can see, it performs the analogous minimum operation for vectors:

[image]

Finally in your main setup, wire it up similarly again and apply a last *Length* node. If you swap the result with the one with values (green dotted line), you should see no difference in the outcome.

[image]

Comment: You could also use a "Mix" node which pretty much works like the right part of your first screenshot.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady oh right, thx for the hint!

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I just tried it and it works amazing for what i wanna do.

Comment: @SprayerFLL welcome. If it solves your problem you can mark the answer as accepted.